# How to scroll past the last item in React Native's FlatList?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, padding, react-native-flatlist

Alright, so I have a horizontal list of items in React Native. I want to be able to have a little bit of white space when I scroll all the way to the end of the list, so I want to have a padding of some sort. What can I do to have a white space only at the end of the FlatList element without it affecting the spacing between my list items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can set `paddingHorizontal` for the FlatList using `contentContainerStyle`.

```
      <FlatList             
      contentContainerStyle={{
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        paddingVertical: 20,
      }}         

    />
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, I noticed I had a typo in my question. I meant for FlatList, not for ScrollView, sorry!

Comment: Edited my answer, please check now. If it helps please accept as correct answer

Comment: That fixed the issue! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two options to achieve this

**Option 1:**

While looping, you can check for the last index and append some right margin/padding.

**Option 2:**

Use `contentContainerStyle` prop to have some horizontal padding, something like below

`contentContainerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: <value> }}`

Let me know if this resolves your issue!

Answer (score 1):

I know that you're probably long moved on, but for future seekers, `FlatList` has a `ListFooterComponent` prop that can be used to create content at the end of the list.

For example:

```js
<FlatList 
  ListFooterComponent={
    <View style={{paddingHorizontal: 20}} />
  }
>
</FlatList>
```

...would add an empty `View` component with padding at the end of a `FlatList` element.